# Update radio button after action button input shiny

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, reactive, action-button

I'm creating a shiny app, and I want one of my tabs to be a 13 question quiz/game. However, I don't want all 13 questions displayed at once. I want to include an action button that when the user presses, the next question is displayed. Currently, both questions are displayed. Also, will I need to create separate action buttons for each question?

Problem 2: Questions 1-5 use the same plot. Questions 6-13 will use a different plot, and I will want both the question and the plot to be changed after question 5. I've provided 2 questions as an example.

In my UI script I have:

```
navbarPage(
  "NEO Guess Who", position = "fixed-top",
 tabPanel("Quiz",
          fluidPage(
            titlePanel(h1("Do you even know us?")),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                radioButtons("q1", "Whose personality is plotted as the purple line?",
                         choices = list("Amy" = "Amy",
                                          "Claire" = "Claire",
                                          "Olivia" = "Olivia",
                                          "Shae" = "Shae",
                                          "Sharon" = "Sharon"),
                           selected = character(0)),
                           textOutput("q1text"),
                           actionButton("q1action", "Next", class = "btn-success"),
                radioButtons("q2", "Whose personality is plotted as the blue line?",
                             choices = list("Amy" = "Amy",
                                            "Claire" = "Claire",
                                            "Olivia" = "Olivia",
                                            "Shae" = "Shae",
                                            "Sharon" = "Sharon"),
                             selected = character(0))),
              mainPanel(
                plotOutput("plot7"))
             )))
         )
```

within the server script, I have:

```
  output$q1text <- renderText({
    q1 <- switch (input$q1,
      Amy = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
      Claire = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
      Olivia = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
      Shae = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
      Sharon = paste("Correct!"),
    )
  })

 observeEvent(input$q1action, {
   updateRadioButtons(session, "q1", choices = c("Amy", "Claire", "Olivia", "Shae", "Sharon"), selected = 0)
   updateRadioButtons(session, "q2", choices = c("Amy", "Claire", "Olivia", "Shae", "Sharon"), selected = 0)
 })
  # both questions are still displayed

  # no legend
  output$plot7 <-  renderPlot({
    {neo_simple <- read.csv("neo_simple.csv", header = T, sep = ",")}
    {neo_simple$domain <- factor(neo_simple$domain, levels = c("neuroticism", "extraversion", "openness", "agree", "conscient"))}
    
    {neoColors <-
        setNames( c('#a6cee3', '#b2df8a', '#fb9a99', '#fdbf6f', '#cab2d6'), 
                  levels(neo_simple$id)  )}
    
    neo_simple %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = domain, y=tscore, group = id, color = id)) +
      geom_point(size = 1.75) +
      scale_color_manual(values = neoColors) +
      geom_line(size = 1.25) +
      theme_bw() +
      ggtitle("NEO Domain Scores") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15))  +
      theme(text = element_text(size=rel(4.5))) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 14))
    
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the 'slickR' package is a possible way:

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

ui <- fluidPage(
  slickROutput("questions", width = "50%")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["questions"]] <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(
      slick_list(
        radioButtons(
          "q1",
          "First question",
          choices = c("Yes", "No")
        ),
        radioButtons(
          "q2",
          "Second question",
          choices = c("True", "False")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really like this, but it doesn't keep my text after radio buttons are clicked. I tried ```observeEvent(input$questions$q1, {
   output$q1text<-renderText({
     switch (input$questions$q1,
             Amy = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
             Claire = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
             Olivia = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
             Shae = paste("Oops, the correct answer is Sharon"),
             Sharon = paste("Correct!"),)
 })})```  Is there a way to call items in the slick_list?